# Defining a function with an array as an argument

Tags: python, arrays, object

I am working in python, trying to be able to put in a data set (eg. (1, 6, 8) that returns a string (eg. 'NO+ F- NO+'). I think that maybe array is not the correct object. I want to be able to plug in large data sets (eg. (1, 1, 6, 1, ..., 8, 8, 6, 1) to return a string.

```
def protein(array):
    ligand = ''
    for i in range(array):
        if i == 1:
            ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
        if i == 6:
            ligand = ligand + 'F-'
        if i == 8:
            ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
    return ligand
```

The following is the input and error code:

```
protein(1, 6, 8)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-a33f3d5c265e> in <module>()
----> 1 protein(1, 6, 8)

TypeError: protein() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

For single inputs, I get the wrong output:

```
protein(1)
Out[45]: ''

protein(6)
Out[46]: 'NO+'
```

If any further clarification is needed, let me know, thanks

Comment: Too many things are wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `def protein(*array):` This allows you to give in any number of arguments. You also must use `for i in array:` instead of `for i in range(array):`

Answer (score 2):

First, you need `*args` as the argument, to accept an arbitrary number of arguments as in your example.

Once you do that, you simply iterate over `args`. The rest of your code is OK, if not entirely idiomatic.

```
def protein(*args):
    ligand = ''
    for i in args:
        if i == 1:
            ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
        if i == 6:
            ligand = ligand + 'F-'
        if i == 8:
            ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
    return ligand
```

A better solution is to set up a mapping from integers to ions(?), then map and join.

```
def protein(*args):
    d = {1: 'NO+', 6: 'F-', 8: 'NO+'}
    return ''.join(d.get(i, '') for i in args)
```

Returning the empty string for a non-existing index is effectively the same as not appending to the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you call it like `protein(1, 6, 8)` you are **not** passing it a tuple: you pass it **three parameters**. Since you defined `protein` with *one* parameter: `array`, that errors.

You can use arbitrary parameters, by using `*args`. But nevertheless this function is still not very elegant nor is it efficient: it will take *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* to calculate the string.

A more declarative and efficient approach is probably to use a dictionary and perform lookups that are then `''.join`ed together:

```
translate = {1: 'NO+', 6: 'F-', 8: 'NO+'}

def protein(*array):
    return ''.join(translate[x] for x in array)
```

In case you want to *ignore* values you pass that are not in the dictionary (for instance ignore `7` in `protein(1,7,6,8)`, you can replace `[x]` with `.get(x, '')`:

```
translate = {1: 'NO+', 6: 'F-', 8: 'NO+'}

def protein(*array):
    return ''.join(translate.get(x, '') for x in array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a list to the protein function. You need to do something like:

```
num_list = [1, 6, 8]
protein(num_list)
```

Or directly:

```
protein([1, 6, 8])
```

Also, you need to fix the for loop after that. At last:

```
def protein(array):
    ligand = ''
    for i in array:
        if i == 1:
            ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
        if i == 6:
            ligand = ligand + 'F-'
        if i == 8:
            ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
    return ligand

print(protein([1, 3, 5]))
```

Output:

```
NO+
```

range() starts from zero(0).

Comment: No do not use `list`... Never name parameters after builtins.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Actually, I didn't understand. Could you tell me clearer?

Answer (score 0):

1) replace 'range(array)' by 'array'
2) put list or tuple in argument when calling the function and not multiple numbers.

```
In [2]: def protein(array):
  ligand = ''
  for i in array:
    if i == 1:
        ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
    if i == 6:
        ligand = ligand + 'F-'
    if i == 8:
        ligand = ligand + 'NO+'
  return ligand
In [3]: protein((1, 6, 8))
Out[3]: 'NO+F-NO+'
```